# python regex multiple optional capture groups

Tags: python, regex, capture-group

I tried to capture multiple groups with ignore cases and don't make any progress for a while.
The string I'm checking can have multiple forms, a few for example

```
<A title="Test title Ch.42" href="http://www.google.com">Test title Ch.42  </a>
<A title="Test title Vol2. Ch.42" href="http://www.google.com">Test title Vol2. Ch.42  </a>
<A title="Test title Vol2.Ch.42" href="http://www.google.com">Test title Vol2.Ch.42  </a>
<A title="Test title \"with multiple quotes\" Ch.42" href="http://www.google.com">Test title "with multiple quotes" Ch.42  </a>
<A title="Test title w1th numb3rs Ch.42" href="http://www.google.com">Test title w1th numb3rs Ch.42  </a>
<A title="Test title no 42" href="http://www.google.com">Test title no 42  </a>
```

So in general the rules are like this:

- The main title in the title tag can contain every character, including numbers and special characters
- The url is a standard url, but can be captures with the (.*) expression without problems
- The Ch. is optional in general
- If the string contains Vol., the Ch. gets mandatory

My current regular expression looks like this:

```
pattern = re.compile('<A title="((.*)(?:Vol.[\d]+){0,1}(?: Ch.){0,1}([\d]+))" href="(.*)">')
```

I want to try and capture:

- The title tag with Vol and Ch including the numbers behind them
- The title without Vol and Ch(and without the numbers behind the Vol and Ch)
- The number behind the Ch.

Would it be better to split the regular expression, what would be better for the performance(it's running over a few thousand strings, so I'd like to keep it performant)?

kind regards Baumchen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not the best tool for parsing in this case, I suppose there are tool exactly for that. However with given examples, you can try this:

```
<a title="(.+?)\s?((Vol(\d+))?\s?\.?(Ch.(\d+)))?"\shref="(.+)">
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aJ9jQ8/2)

- `group(1)` - title,
- `group(2)` - Vol with num or/with Ch with num,
- `group(3)` - Vol with number
- `group(4)` - only number (of Vol)
- `group(5)` - Ch with number
- `group(6)` - only number (of Ch.)
- `group(7)` - URL

Comment: thanks a lot worked perfectly, what tools would you recommend for this case?

Comment: @Baumchen I happy it helps. I have not Python backgroud, but I think any html parser could deal with it, at leas partialy (maybe [this one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html))